# Asymptotic expansion of $n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1)$, if $a > 0$, to terms of $O\Big(\frac{1}{n^3}\Big)$

Tags: asymptotics

Asymptotic expansion of $n(\sqrt[n]{a} - 1)$,  if $a > 0$, to terms of $O\Big(\dfrac{1}{n^3}\Big)$

Attempt:
$n((1+(a-1))^\frac{1}{n} - 1) = n(1 + \frac{1}{n} a + \dfrac{\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}-1)}{2} a^2+ \cdots - 1)$

$n(\frac{1}{n} a + \dfrac{\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}-1)}{2} a^2 + \cdots ) = a + \frac{\frac{1}{n}-1}{2} a^2 + \cdots$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to arrive at answer or how to proceed?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh! i didn't knew. Thanks will take from next time.

Comment: just expand the  equation up to $\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sqrt[n]{a}=e^{\frac1n\log a}=1+\frac1n\,\log a+\frac1{2!}\,\frac1{n^2}(\log a)^2+\dots
$$

Comment: So the answer should be $\log a + \frac 1{2!} \frac{1}{n} (\log a)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{n^2} (\log a)^3 + \frac{1}{4!}\frac{1}{n^3} (\log a)^4$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.